# Vibration when brakes applied

Tags: vibration

Just need a little hand diagnosing an issue.

Car in question is a 2014 Mazda 5 with about 75k miles.

When applying brakes I get an annoyingly strong vibration, both through the wheel and the rest of the car.

It only happens at very specific speeds (decelerating 40mph to 35mph) and when applying the brakes in what I'd call a medium light fashion. Had the alignment recently checked and the tire pressure is spot on. Pads look good.

Bent rotor / wheel rim or something else entirely?

Comment: Year/Make/Model/Milage? Could be warped rotor, could be a failing brake hose. Could be sticking slide pins. Are the Pad shims present and correct?

Comment: Have you checked that the lugs are torqued to spec? If they're even a little loose, the rotors could wander laterally a bit.

Comment: You have one or more warped front brake rotors, this is a classic symptom of you issue. Replace the rotors and brake pads.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is the brake rotors. If there is enough material left, they can be machined to be straight and true again, otherwise buy new ones. Always replace the brake pads when installing refinished or new rotors.

Inspect the calipers and lube the slides to ensure the caliper is able to move freely to apply even pressure to the rotor. Otherwise, it can cause rotor to prematurely fail.

Some less likely causes are wheel balance and suspension components. Wheel balance can cause vibrations at specific speeds. Can't hurt to have it checked if it has been a while.

Lastly, check all the suspension joints, bearings and bushings. Loose or worn components can allow vibrations to be felt throughout the car.